# Clear Text on PDF context iphone sdk

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf

I want to change text in PDF after drawing it on Context.
 I have also tried it by using following code.

```
      CGContextRef context =  UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGAffineTransform ctm = CGContextGetCTM(context);

 CGRect xformRect = CGRectApplyAffineTransform(frameRect, ctm);

 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:text];

UIGraphicsSetPDFContextURLForRect( url, xformRect );



UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:frameRect];
[button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[button setAccessibilityLabel:url.absoluteString];

CGContextSaveGState(context);
// CGContextClearRect(context, frameRect);
```

In this I am getting  null values in URL.absoluteString

So I just want to change it  with my custom Code

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Comment: If `url` is `nil` then `text` isn't a valid URL.

Comment: In this case this above code is in particular method  I am calling this method two times.... SO I just want to say that first time I m getting nil URL and second time I am getting proper URL.....

Comment: In my case Once It comes  null on PDF It does not  overwrite new URL which come properly..... how to overwrite text